# Running Python Script from Cron.d

Tags: python, django, cron

I'm trying to run a Django management command via a crontab installed to /etc/cron.d/mycron on Ubuntu.

I first tested my basic setup by writing the following to /etc/cron.d/mycron:

```
* * * * * root command echo "Test $(date)" 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log
```

And I confirmed /tmp/mycron.log was updated once a minute and contains the expected text.

I then tried the following variations using my actual management command:

```
* * * * * root command python /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log

* * * * * root command /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log

* * * * * root command /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log

* * * * * python /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log

* * * * * /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log

* * * * * /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log
```

And even though the log file is generated, it contains none of the expected logging text my management command outputs.

After each variation, I run `sudo touch /etc/cron.d/` to reload cron. Even if there was an error in my Python code, I'd expect some sort of error message to get logged.

I've checked `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, and the only errors it shows are for crontabs that don't start with "root", for which it gives me the error:

```
Error: bad username; while reading /etc/cron.d/mycron
```

For all the others, I see something like:

```
Oct  7 10:54:01 localhost CRON[27805]: (root) CMD (/path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log)
```

But nothing's written to the log, and the database changes I expect to happen aren't occuring. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output you need is either in `/tmp/mycron.log`, or mailed to `root`. Type `mail` from under `root` to check.

Also, why are you trying different variations? The syntax of crontab files is strictly defined (`man crontab -S 5`), for /etc/crontab it is:

```
min hour day month weekday user cmdline
```

for personal crontabs, it is:

```
min hour day month weekday cmdline
```

You can't omit user name in /etc/crontab, neither you can use `/usr/bin/python` in place of user name.

You also don't need the word `command`, it only works because there is built-in bash function with this name which apparently just runs a command from it's arguments.

The correct line must be either of:

```
* * * * * root /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log
* * * * * root /usr/bin/python /path/to/my/script/manage.py mycommand 2>&1 >> /tmp/mycron.log
```

In the first case, `manage.py` must be executable (`chmod +x manage.py`) and it's first line must be `#!/usr/bin/python`, or whatever your python interpreter path is.

Comment: Did you read my post? I said I'm not seeing errors in either syslog or /tmp/mycron.log.

Comment: @Cerin there is nothing about looking inside /tmp/mycron.log in the question. Please update it to make it more clear what is your problem.

Comment: @Cerin see my updated answer. It is possible the output is mailed; run `mail` to check.